# Ошибка при получении списка участников канал telegram

Tags: python, telegram, api, telethon

Пытаюсь собрать список участников чужого публичного телеграм канала. В результате выходит operational error "database is locked". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.
Код программы:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
api_id = 1
api_hash = 'z'
client = TelegramClient('d', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
channel = client.get_entity('k')
def get_channel_users(channel):
    offset = 0
    limit = 100
    all_users = []

    while True:
        result = client(GetParticipantsRequest(
            channel=channel,
            filter=ChannelParticipantsSearch(''),
            offset=offset,
            limit=limit,
            hash=0
        ))
        users = result.users
        all_users.extend(users)
        if len(users) < limit:
            break
        offset += limit
    return all_users
users = get_channel_users(channel)
for user in users:
    print(user.first_name, user.last_name, user.username)
```

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)